# Flashdata not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to set flash data in my project. I tried setting all flash data but it doesn't work, why?

**My model:**

```
public function deleteCamera($id_camera)
    {
        $this->db->where('id_camera', $id_camera);
        $this->db->delete('camera');
    }
```

**My controller:**

```
public function delete($id_camera)
    {
        $terdaftar=$this->Crud_model->cameraTerdaftar($id_camera);
        if ($terdaftar) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('terhapus', 'Camera Berhasil Dihapus');
            $this->Crud_model->deleteCamera($id_camera);
            redirect('Home', 'refresh');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('fail', 'Tidak dapat menghapus, Camera tersebut telah digunakan');
            redirect('Home','refresh');
        }
    }
```

**My view:**

```
<?php if (validation_errors()) { ?>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></strong>
  </div>
<?php } else if ($this->session->flashdata('terhapus')) { ?>
   <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="alert alert-danger">
     <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('terhapus'); ?></strong>
   </div>
<?php } else if ($this->session->flashdata('fail')) { ?>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px" class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('fail'); ?></strong>
  </div>
<?php } else if ($this->session->flashdata('sudah_input')) { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Put the `flashdata` outside of   `if (validation_errors())`  block,its independent from  `validation_errors` .

Answer (score -1):

in order to display your flashdata to your page, do it something like this.

```
if($this->session->flashdata('terhapus')){ 
   echo $this->session->flashdata('terhapus'); 
}
```

you can add **style** and **js** script on it.

Comment: to your page view page @rizkyalviandra.

Comment: how to display flashdata if my contidion is false or error?

Comment: Yeah i know @RajeevRanjan. you need to set it equal to the controller. as you can  see he want to display the flash data in a view. so how come that his flashdata will display if there is no condition was set?

Comment: in other words, to echo the flash data you need it to set equal to the controller before it will redirect to view page.